# Card removal and marginal hands

Tags: probability

We know that big cards like ace and king are played more pre flop

For me in late position card removal would not really change how you play AK.

What about 88? Does card removal make it any more playable multi-way?  Say 4 in the pot and not folds in front of you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/410/are-mucked-and-burnt-cards-significant-in-odds-calculation/8886#8886) it got me thinking. See my answer.

If they are playing this 77+, A9s+, KTs+, QTs+, AJo+, KQo top 10% then they only have an 8 12/296 = 4.05%

The chance of no 8 is 1 - (284/296)^4 = .84

So if you remove 10 cards from the deck not 2 and assume .84 of the time the 2 8s are still available then your chance of flopping trips is 12.6% = 1/7.9.  If you take random (50 unknown) then 11.3%.  So odds went up by 10%.

Pot odds 6.9 : 1
2.5 bb raise and 3 calls = 3 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 / 5 = 4.6 : 1
Still not getting immediate odds to call

A limp and 3 calls = 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 / 2 = 5.5 : 1
Still not getting immediate odds to call
And at that point cannot assume late callers are playing top 10%

Back to card removal is real but it does not really matter

Found a spot where card removal matters.  Multi way against 4 top 10%  56s, 67s, 78s has 20% equity and JTs has less 16% equity. Against 3 playing top 10% 56s, 67s, 78s has 19% equity.